# generate list using a particular key from a list of objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Haven't used Python much in a couple years and having a hard time remembering how to do this.

```
src = [
    {a: 1},
    {a: 2, b: 'foo'},
    {a: 3}
]

#python magic here outputs:
#[1,2,3]
```

*Edit for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which of these two you want:

```
def get_all_values(list_o_dicts):
    return [value for a_dict in list_o_dicts for value in a_dict.values()]
```

… or…

```
def get_values(list_o_dicts, key):
    return [a_dict[key] for a_dict in list_o_dicts]
```

Here's both of them in action, using an example that (a) is actually valid Python, and (b) has other values, so the distinction makes a difference:

```
>>> src = [
...     {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
...     {'a': 3}
... ]
>>> get_all_values(src)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> get_values(src, 'a')
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. For the sake of clarity, what kind of operation is this called in Python? Is it a form of list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, these are both list comprehensions. The first one is a list comprehension with two nested `for` clauses, which isn't very common or readable (and I would usually use `itertools.chain` to flatten `[a_dict.values() for a_dict in list_o_dicts]` instead, but I didn't want to bring in anything extra to explain). The second one is pretty much the paradigm case of list comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've been away in node.js land for several years and jumping back into Python with both feet.

Comment: @Geuis: If only Mozilla and Adobe hadn't been so stubborn about static typing, ES4 would have passed, and node.js would have had Python-style array comprehensions…